# .NET EventHandler Delegate - Why still an "EventArgs" parameter if it "will handle an event that has no event data."?

Tags: c#, .net

Probably my head is a kind of scrambled now, but I'm having some difficulty understanding the description about the already-defined EventHandler delegate of .NET. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says it "Represents the method that will handle an event that has no event data." Then if every time we use it we'll definitely not pass data, why the argument "EventArgs" is still there? Its existence makes every time we have to pass an EventArgs.Empty to it which is quite tedious. Is there any particular reason for it, or is it just for compatibility and code flexibility? I'm new to .NET so sorry if this question seems naive. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that may be a typo in the documentation. Further down it says that EventArg is used to pass event data, which  is true. But if there is no data, then pass EventArgs.Empty. as you said. But I think the parameter text is confused.

Comment: If it is that tedious for you to write `EventArgs.Empty` then create a helper method that does that for you. **Or** declare your own delegate for `sender` only. I would only recommend the 2nd option if the events are internal. Otherwise, you risk breaking the expected behavior of event handlers. However, as @BenVoigt points out in his answer, you will also risk breaking an unknown number of event handlers in the future should you decide to include `EventArgs` with data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It provides:

- Consistency
- The ability to write a "universal" event receiver, because all handlers have two arguments, and the second argument is always a subtype of `EventArgs`.  Together with argument contravariance (which delegates support), a handler with the `EventHandler` signature can be attached to any event

  ```
  delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
  ```
- The ability to add new data to your event without breaking existing handlers.  Existing code will happily use a subset of the available properties in an `EventArgs`-derived object.  But increasing the number of parameters would cause all existing subscribers to fail to compile.

Comment: Ack! The answer Tim found gives these same reasons 5 years ago.  Cast close-as-dupe votes instead.

Comment: "a handler with the EventHandler signature can be attached to any event [...]", that follows this pattern.  However, because not all events follow this pattern, this statement doesn't hold true, greatly reducing its usefulness.

Comment: Well didn't find that duplicate... Guess I didn't quite use the correct keywords. Thanks all the same! That's about what I wanted to say with "compatibility and code flexibility", but I couldn't express it with clear and coherent terms, probably because I still don't have a proficiency with .NET

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The EventArgs class is the **base type** for all event data classes. EventArgs is also the class you use when an event does not have any data associated with it. When you create an event that is only meant to notify other classes that something happened and does not need to pass any data, include the EventArgs class as the second parameter in the delegate. You can pass the EventArgs.Empty value when no data is provided. The EventHandler delegate includes the EventArgs class as a parameter.

It's the natural behavior of the base type.